# Extract the numbers part from characters

Tags: r, string, character-encoding

I used read.table to read in a UTF-8 encoded csv file and one column showed as:

```
[1] 16渭g/m鲁 15渭g/m鲁 14渭g/m鲁 15渭g/m鲁 12渭g/m鲁 16渭g/m鲁
[7] 12渭g/m鲁 15渭g/m鲁 11渭g/m鲁 15渭g/m鲁 12渭g/m鲁 15渭g/m鲁
```

After I used as.character to convert this column into character and View them, it showed as:

```
16ug/m3
```

etc.

What i need is the number part of this character string. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> gsub("[^0-9.]", "", "13.2sometextinthemiddleofnumbers12")
[1] "13.212"
```

Comment: This is why i LOVE stackoverflow! Thank you Cory!

Comment: I searched for the gsub function description and the ocde here is pretty easy to understand.